# Grails 1.3.3: controller.redirectArgs.action not populated

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-controller

Does anyone knows what happened to controller.redirectArgs.action in the latest version of Grails (1.3.3)? It used to work properly but now I get NPE when I use it.

```
class FooController {
    def someRedirect = {
        redirect(action:"bar")
    }
}

class FooControllerTests extends grails.test.ControllerUnitTestCase {
    void testSomeRedirect() {
        controller.someRedirect()
        assertEquals "bar", controller.redirectArgs.action
    }
}
```

In this case controller.redirectArgs is already null...

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the comparing the action to a string. the following worked for me, where

The controller looks something like:

```
class SomeObjectController {

  def index = { redirect(action:list,params:params) }

  def list = {
     params.max = Math.min( params.max ? params.max.toInteger() : 10,  100)

     [ 
      someObjectInstanceList: someObject.list( params ), 
      somObjectInstanceTotal: someObject.count() 
     ]
  }
}
```

and the test class would look something like:

```
class SomeObjectControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
    void testIndexRedirectToListAction(){
        controller.index()
        assertEquals controller.list, controller.redirectArgs.action
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I followed the documentation here: http://www.grails.org/Testing+Controllers

I'm calling:
assertEquals "nextAvailable", controller.redirectArgs.action

and I'm getting the following:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<nextAvailable> but was:<com.***.***.XxxxXxxxController$_closure1@3da2cda9>
```

I seem to be getting back a closure and I'm trying to figure out how to get the action name.

I found the solution here: www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails10209/index.html?ca=drs-

If you do a quick ctrl/cmd + F, you'll find that this assert passes:

```
assertEquals controller.nextAvailable, controller.redirectArgs.action
```

This passes as well:

```
assertEquals controller.nextAvailable, controller.redirectArgs[action]
```